# asp.net gridview sorting datatable + different datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a grid view which displays different reports ( calling different stored procedures). i have implemented sorting functionality, using the `onSorting` event. In the sorting event I have the following code:

```
 DataTable table = getReportDT("ReportName", "storedProcName");
 table.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression + direction;    
 gridView.DataSource = table;    
 gridView.DataBind();
```

I'm currently passing in the Name of the report and it's respective stored procedure, however i would like to have this method as generic as possible and if the user chooses another report name from the dropdown list the datatable will update accordingly. i tried passing in the parameters using a property however it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a DropDownList in the aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Report 1" Value="Report1_SP"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Report 2" Value="Report2_SP"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Report 3" Value="Report3_SP"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind get the name and sp from the DropDownList:

```
DataTable table = getReportDT(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text,DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Comment: what is gettReportDT here ? where to call SP here ?